# ember multi level has many serialization issue

Tags: serialization, ember.js

I am facing some issues with my serialization of model. Below is a detailed code which will show how my current model and corresponding serializers look.

1. User model

   ```
   export default Model.extend({
     name: attr('string'),
     accounts: hasMany('account', {async: false})
   });
   ```
2. Account model

   ```
    export default Model.extend({
        type: attr('string'),
        transactions: hasMany('transaction')
    })
   ```
3. Transaction model

   ```
    export default Model.extend({
       date: attr('string'),
       amount: attr('number')
    })
   ```

So basically its a hasMany within another hasMany.

Serializers looks like this:

1. base serializer:

   ```
    export default BaseSerializer.extend({
       keyForAttribute(key) {
         return key.underscore();
       },
       keyForRelationship(key, relationship) {
          return key.underscore();
       }
      });
   ```
2. User serializer:

   ```
   export default BaseSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
      account: { embedded: 'always' }
    }
   });
   ```
3. Account serializer:

   ```
   export default BaseSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    attrs: {
      transaction: { embedded: 'always' }
    }
   });
   ```

Now when I am invoking api call which gives me a json response where user model has a property named as accounts: which internally have another property called as transactions, I am expecting them to serialize but somehow its not working. have I done anything wrong here? Please advise as I am new to ember and still learning it.

Base serializer is:

```
   export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
      keyForRelationship(key, relationship) {
        return key.underscore();
      }
   })
```

Serialized json

I dont have it but from the console logs, seems like only user model is getting serialized as when I tried to print console.log(user.get('accounts').get('firstObject').get('type') then i saw undefined there.

What I want is:

```
{

  name: "bhavya"
  accounts: [
   {
     type : 'savings',
     transactions: [
       {  
         amount: 500
       }
     ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: What is your `BaseSerializer`? Please also include an example of the serialized JSON - both as it is with your current implementation and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: updated my post

Comment: I'm confused that you don't have the serialized JSON. I'm talking about the payload send to your server. If you don't have it yet, you could also call [`serialize` method](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.4/classes/DS.Model/methods/serialize?anchor=serialize)  of a user record.

Comment: oh, the payload sent to server? Its a post request to make a transaction which returns the above mentioned desired response. My api makes a post request to server with some payload and in return sends back user details which the structure I mentioned. I want that structured to get serialized but ember not doing it for me (may be some issue in my implementation)

Comment: You are asking about serialization. Normally a model is serialized for sending it to your backend as part of a `POST` or `PATCH`/`PUT` request. What I'm asking you to include in your question is not only how your serialized record should look like but only how it's looking with your current implementation. Setting up an [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/) would be even better but it could be hard if you aren't experienced with it.